# ¿Es posible agregar un captcha en Android e IOs desde Genexus?

Tags: genexus, captcha, recaptcha

Con GX17 U9 generando en .NET hemos agregado captchas a aplicaciones web, con los UC:

- https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15963,reCAPTCHA+User+Control
- https://wiki.k2btools.com/k2btools/servlet/wiki?20219,K2BToolsCaptchaProvider

pero estos funcionan sólo en web, ¿hay alguna manera de agregarlos a una aplicación Android e IOs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta del soporte de GX:

*"El control capcha para móvil no existe, hay que crearlo por aparte
Deberías crear uno propio siguiendo esta guía:
https://github.com/genexuslabs/SDExtensionsSample* "